# How are vertices transformed in WebGL in indexed and non-indexed geometries?

Tags: webgl

I am trying to digest these two links:

https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader

The pipeline overview says that vertex shader runs before the primitive assembly.

The second one mentions this:

> A vertex shader is (usually) invariant with its input. That is, within a single Drawing Command, **two vertex shader invocations that get the exact same input attributes will return binary identical results**. Because of this, if OpenGL can detect that a vertex shader invocation is being given the same inputs as a previous invocation, it is allowed to reuse the results of the previous invocation, instead of wasting valuable time executing something that it already knows the answer to.
>
> OpenGL implementations generally do not do this by actually comparing the input values (that would take far too long). Instead, this optimization typically only happens when using indexed rendering functions. **If a particular index is specified more than once (within the same Instanced Rendering), then this vertex is guaranteed to result in the exact same input data.**
>
> Therefore, implementations employ a cache on the results of vertex shaders. **If an index/instance pair comes up again, and the result is still in the cache**, then the vertex shader is not executed again. **Thus, there can be fewer vertex shader invocations than there are vertices specified**.

So if i have two quads with two triangles each:

indexed:

```
verts: { 0 1 2 3 }
tris:  { 0 1 2 }
         { 1 2 3 }
```

soup:

```
verts: { 0 1 2 3 4 5 }
tris:  { 0 1 2 } 
             { 3 4 5 }
```

and perhaps a vertex shader that looks like this:

```
uniform mat4 mvm;
uniform mat4 pm;

attribute vec3 position;

void main (){
  vec4 res;
  for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ){
     res = pm * mvm * vec4(position,1.);
  }
gl_Position = res;
```

**Should I care that one has 4 vertices while the other one has 6?** Is this even true from gpu to gpu, will one invoke the vertex shader 4 times vs 6? How is this affected by the cache:

> If an index/instance pair comes up again, **and the result is still in the cache**...

How is the primitive number related to performance here? In both cases i have the same amount of primitives.

In the case of a very simple fragment shader, but an expensive vertex shader:

```
void main(){
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.);
}
```

And a tessellated quad (100x100 segments) can i say that the indexed version **will** run faster, or **can** run faster, or maybe say **nothing**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everything in GPUs according to the spec you can say nothing. It's up to the driver and GPU. In reality though in your example 4 vertices will run faster than 6 pretty much everywhere?

Search for vertex order optimization and lots of articles come up

[Linear-Speed Vertex Cache Optimisation](https://tomforsyth1000.github.io/papers/fast_vert_cache_opt.html)

[Triangle Order Optimization](http://gameangst.com/?p=9)

[AMD Triangle Order Optimization Tool](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/amd-tootle)

[Triangle Order Optimization for Graphics Hardware Computation Culling](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Nehab_2006_TOO/index.php)

unrelated but another example of the spec vs realtiy is that according to the spec depth testing happens AFTER the fragment shader runs (otherwise you couldn't set `gl_FragDepth` in the fragment shader. In reality though as long as the results are the same the driver/GPU can do whatever it wants so fragment shaders that don't set `gl_FragDepth` or `discard` certain fragments are depth tested first and only run if the test passes.

Comment: When the stencil and depth tests happen is a whole different topic of confusion, for which i probably want to ask another question :) Why did you write `In reality though in your example 4 vertices will run faster than 6 pretty much everywhere?` as a question though? Sounds like it goes against the "say nothing"?

Comment: In the example i gave the 100x100 plane would give `10201` vertices, a triangle soup `60000`. Common sense tells me that yeah, the smaller amount will render faster, but reading through the original two links made me realize i don't understand how it works. Also for the longest time i've mostly heard "triangle count" being referred to as the metric of how light/performant game models are, while it seems the vertex count would be more important.

Comment: That's why i was thinking the example of super heavy vertex computation, and a much higher number of vertices between the same tri count of indexed/soup in the second example. Without knowing how costly is to rasterize a triangle, i'd guess the first example would render 50% longer in the case of the soup. Thanks for the links, and the answer, i need to digest the matter :)

Comment: How it works is there is a cache. So if you compute vertex index 1 and then use 1000 other vertices and then use vertex 1 again, if it's in the cache your vertex shader not called again. If it's not in the cache your vertex shader is called again. Every GPU has a different sized cache for vertices so YMMV. As for perf fillrate is more important. So 100 fullscreen 1920x1080 simple solid color planes will draw much slower than 1million 1 pixels triangles (both in a single draw call).  Samplers also have caches so jumping around a texture is slow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the articles. It is very educational.

Comment: So the cache check will happen during the primitive assembly? I'm still a bit confused, as it says that this step happens after the vertex shader execution. I imagined the entire vertex list is processed by the time indices are even used. How does it know to look for things in cache before doing the primitives? Do you have book recommendations that dive deeper into this. Graphics books i have usually cover much more math and algorithms than gpu designs and dont go as deep into the rendering pipeline. Once again, much appreciated!

Comment: If this were jeopardy `Samplers also have caches so jumping around a texture is slow` what kind of a question i could ask here :D I'm super curious about this, as i've seen it mentioned in many papers/articles but i never understood how it worked. Would jumping around be something like `texture2D(samp, someIndex_IsItRelevant + someRandFunction())` vs `texture2D(samp, someIndex + someUniformOrConst[ i ])`

Comment: A good example of a random texture read is indexed graphics based emu. `index = texture(eightBitTexture, uv); color = texture(palette, vec2(index, .5))`; Which value you read out of `palette` is basically random so unless the entire texture fits in the cache then there will be a cache miss a large percentage of fragment shader iterations. palette might fit in the cache since it's likely only 1k but you get the idea. The GPU caches some portion of the larger texture. If you reference something outside that portion then you get a cache miss. Too many misses = very slow.

Comment: Google-Fu results: [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15869-f11/www/lectures/08_mem_hierarchy.pdf), [this too](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02308.pdf), [and maybe this](http://meseec.ce.rit.edu/551-projects/spring2015/3-2.pdf)