# Three.js indexed BufferGeometry vs. InstancedBufferGeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to learn more about performant geometries in THREE.js, and have come to understand that an indexed BufferGeometry and InstancedBufferGeometry are the two most performant geometry types.

My understanding so far is that in an indexed BufferGeometry, vertices that are re-used in a geometry are only added to the geometry once, and each instance of a given re-used vertex are referenced by their index position in the vertex array.

My understanding of the InstancedBufferGeometry is that this geometry allows one to create a "blueprint" of an object, send one copy of that object's vertices to a shader, then use custom attributes to modify each copy of the blueprint's position, rotation, scale, etc. [[source](https://github.com/nicoptere/FluffyPredator)]

I'd like to better understand: are there cases in which an indexed BufferGeometry will be more performant than the InstancedBufferGeometry.

Also, in the InstancedBufferGeometry, are there WebGL maximum parameters (such as maximum vertices per mesh) that one must consider so as to avoid making a mesh too large? How are the vertices in an InstancedBufferGeometry counted?

If anyone could help clarify the situations in which indexed BufferGeometry and InstancedBufferGeometry should be used, and the performance ceilings of InstancedBufferGeometry, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I saw you mention `IndexedBufferGeometry` in another post but i still have no idea where you found it. Is this a `THREE.js` thing?

Comment: There is a value that you can query that will give you the size of the index. It can be 16bit which means that you can only address 65536 vertices in one draw call. But it can also be 32bit with this limitation much higher.

Comment: Might find this interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798175/how-are-vertices-transformed-in-webgl-in-indexed-and-non-indexed-geometries

Comment: I've edited the title to say `instanced BufferGeometry` instead of `InstancedBufferGeometry` simply because there exists no `InstancedBufferGeometry` in three.js and never has?

Comment: @pailhead what do you mean? `new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();` is a valid constructor, at least in v92...

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, there is no new `THREE.IndexedBufferGeometry()` constructor, that's true

Comment: I've worked with three for a few years and have never ever seen that class. Must be the latest addition in v92. Apologies for editing.

Comment: Oh, i see. May i assume that you don't actually have any code written, and that you're asking an abstract, theoretical question? Perhaps this should be tagged as [tag:webgl] instead of [tag:three.js].

Comment: @pailhead I actually have too much code written! I'm reading several MB of textures and visualizing lots of images. Here's the project: https://github.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot I'm implementing custom shaders for the project now...

Comment: So to reiterate for anyone else reading this. `THREE.IndexedBufferGeometry` is not part of `three.js`. That class does not exist.  `THREE.BufferGeometry` does exist and is one of the core features of three.js. `BufferGeometry` has a method, called `setIndex` which takes a `THREE.BufferAttribute`. Setting the index makes an instance of `BufferGeometry` indexed or not.

Comment: OK, I'm a firm believer that ambiguity hurts software :). The question is valuable, i just think it needs to be improved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> [...] IndexedBufferGeometry and InstancedBufferGeometry are the two most performant geometry types.

Yes, BufferGeometries in general are the most performant way to deal with geometry-data as they store data in exactly the format that is used in the communication with the GPU via WebGL. Any plain Geometry is internally converted to a BufferGeometry before rendering.

You are also correct in your descriptions of the indexed and instanced geometries, but I'd like to note one more detail: In an indexed geometry, the instructions for the GPU how to assemble the triangles are separated from the vertex-data and presented to the GPU in a special index-attribute (as opposed to being an implied part of the vertices for non-indexed arrays).

> I'd like to better understand: are there cases in which an IndexedBufferGeometry will be more performant than the InstancedBufferGeometry.

They do different things at different levels, so I don't think there are many use-cases where a choice between them makes much sense.
In fact, you can even create an instanced geometry based on a "blueprint"-geometry that has is an indexed BufferGeometry.

Let's dive a bit into the details to explain. An instanced geometry allows you to render multiple "clones" of the same "blueprint"-geometry in a single draw-call.
The first part of this, the creation of the blueprint, is identical to rendering a single geometry. For this, the attributes (positions, normals, uv-coordinates and possibly the index for an indexed geometry) need to be transferred to the GPU.

The special thing for instanced geometries are some extra attributes (in three.js `InstancedBufferAttribute`). These control how many times the geometry will be rendered and provide some instance-specific values. A typical use-case would be to have an additional vec3-attribute for the instance-position and a vec4-attribute for the quaternion per instance. But it really could be anything else as well.

In the vertex-shader, these special attributes look just like any other attribute and you need to manually apply the instance-specific updates per vertex. So instead of this:

```
attribute vec3 position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

You would have something like this:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 instanceOffset; // this is the InstancedBufferAttribute
void main() {
  gl_Position = 
    projectionMatrix 
    * modelViewMatrix 
    * vec4(position + instanceOffset, 1.0);
}
```

What you don't see here is that the vertex-shader in the instanced version will not only be called once per vertex of your geometry (as it is the case for regular rendering) but once per vertex and instance.

So there isn't actually any magic going on, instanced geometries are in fact nothing but a very efficient way to express duplication of entire geometries.

> Also, in the InstancedBufferGeometry, are there WebGL maximum parameters (such as maximum vertices per mesh) that one must consider so as to avoid making a mesh too large?

I am not sure about that, but I didn't encounter any so far. If you are aware that rendering 1000 instances of an object with 1000 vertices will invoke the vertex-shader a million times that should help your judgement of performance implications.

> If anyone could help clarify the situations in which IndexedBufferGeometry and InstancedBufferGeometry should be used, and the performance ceilings of InstancedBufferGeometry, I'd be very grateful.

You can (and maybe should) use indexed geometries for almost any kind of geometry. But they are not free of drawbacks:

- when using indices, all attributes will get the same treatment. So for instance, you can't use per-face colors in indexed geometries (see [Access to faces in BufferGeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141438/access-to-faces-in-buffergeometry/42167138#42167138))
- for point-clouds or geometries with little repeated vertices, they will do more harm than good (due to the extra amount of memory/bandwidth needed for the index)

most of the time though they will get a performance-benefit:

- less memory/bandwidth required for vertex-data
- GPUs can cache results of vertex-shaders and re-use them for repeated vertices (so, in an optimal case you'd end up with one VS-invocation per stored vertex, not per index)

For instanced geometries

- if you have a larger number of somewhat similar objects where the differences can be expressed in just a few numbers, go for instanced geometries (simple case: render copies of the same object at different locations, complex case: render a forest by changing the tree's geometry based on some instance-attribute or render a crowd of people by changing the individual persons pose with an instance-attribute)
- another thing I found quite inspiring: rendering of fat lines using instancing: use instancing to render a bunch of line-segments where each line-segment consists of 6 triangles (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/lines/LineSegmentsGeometry.js by @WestLangley)

Drawbacks:

- as it is right now, there is no builtin-support for using regular materials together with instanced geometries. You have to write your shaders yourself. (to be precise: there is a way to do it, but it requires some intimate knowledge of how the three.js shaders work).

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß thanks very much for this very helpful answer. Do you know of any examples of indexed and instanced geometries in THREE.js? If so, I'd love to see one! I'm digging in deep on a scene that basically draws a bunch of quads, each of which has one texture, so I thought I might as well go full monty.

Comment: @duhaime most of the built-in geometries are indexed by default. One of the simpler ones: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js#L74-L111, for instancing, I would refer you to a codepen I wrote some time ago that has lots of explanatory comments: https://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/YNrvpY?editors=0010

Comment: Unfortunately you are right about the drawbacks. https://github.com/pailhead/three-instanced-mesh this exists as an attempt to mitigate the problem.